# How to show progress dialog even touch the screen in Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using progress dialog to retrieve  Flickr photos, my requirement is to 1)Display  progress dialog even I touch the screen and also 
2)If I click back button the asyn task should cancel and go back to previous page

second requirement here i tried, it is coming but i am not getting  first requirement. could you please help me to solve this issues

this is my onPreExecute code

```
 DownloadTask asyncClassObject;
       private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


          protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                     **asyncClassObject = new DownloadTask();**
                        // Showing progress dialog      
                        pDialog =  ProgressDialog.show(Flickeralbumlist.this,"Flickr Album","please wait...",true,true,new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {


                                DownloadTask.this.cancel(true);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }); 
                        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        **asyncClassObject.execute();**
            }
    }

          @Override
                public void onBackPressed() {
                                 // cancel AsyncTask
                            if (asyncClassObject != null)
                                asyncClassObject.cancel(true);
                             // dismiss ProgressDialog
                            if(pDialog !=null)
                               if(pDialog.isShowing())
                                 pDialog.dismiss();

                             super.onBackPressed();
                }
```

Here I used this line "pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);" even though I didn't get proper output, could you please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: Display progress dialog **even** i touch the screen! Can you elaborate?

Comment: `even though i didn't get proper output` what output currently you are getting?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK now i am getting if i touch the screen while progress is loading my current page is closed and come back to previous page. this is my issues if i touch the screen while progress is loading, it should not close my current page. could you help me

Comment: @Tushar if i touch the screen while progress is loading it should not close my current page

Comment: @dawoodrizwan: ok add following lines then try it : `pDialog.setCancelable(false);pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: ^ That's the solution.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i tried as what you said but it is not coming just check my update question i add two lines as what you said

Comment: @dawoodrizwan: move both lines after ` }); ` line

Comment: @Tushar  i tried but it is not coming can you just check my update question and reply me, what i have to do exactly

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it is working but now my second requirement is not working. previously it is working but now it is not working, what i have to do for second reqirement

Comment: Override `onBackPress` and finish the activity.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK just check my update question i am not sure whether that is correct or not but still i am not getting expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)Display progress dialog even I touch the screen

Add `setCancelable` after creating `ProgressDialog` :

```
pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

> 2)If I click back button the asyn task should cancel and go back to
>   previous page

call `AsyncTask.cancel` with true value:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // cancel AsyncTask
    if (asyncClassObject != null)
        asyncClassObject.cancel(true);

    // dismiss ProgressDialog
    if(pDialog !=null)
       if(pDialog.isShowin())
         pDialog.dismiss()
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: this is ok but  i am asking how to use onbackkey press to finish the activity just can you see my updated question code i override onbackkey even though i am not getting, if i put pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);,pDialog.setCancelable(false);  before oncancel override means my back is working but touch is not working. if i changed these two lines after ); my touch is working but back button is not working i need both should work

Comment: @dawoodrizwan: make sure you are not Overriding both `onBackPressed()` and `onKeyDown` use only one method

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K i have one doubt, this is my asyn task class name                private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> what i have to put instead of  asyncClassObject in onbackpressed method  i tried to put DownloadTask  instead of asyncClassObject is it right?

Comment: @dawoodrizwan: Create a Object of `DownloadTask` class at class level like `DownloadTask  asyncClassObject;`   initialized it before calling `execute` method like `asyncClassObject =new  DownloadTask();asyncClassObject.execute(...)` now use `asyncClassObject` object in everywhere

Comment: just check it man i updated my question code i tried as what you said but i am not sure whether it is correct or not, i am getting "asyncClassObject cannot be resolved to a variable" error i know my object is not taking   could you please tell me exactly what i have to do

Comment: @dawoodrizwan: Move `DownloadTask asyncClassObject;` line before `   private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{` line

Comment: @dawoodrizwan: and where you are calling `new DownloadTask().execute()` ?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K actually where i have to call that execute method, now i am calling after this two line  pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);  just check it..

Comment: @dawoodrizwan: then use `asyncClassObject.cancel(true)` line in `onBackPressed`

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K i am following what you said but still i am not getting correct output i am totally confused could you please edit my code and update correct code

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K please help me update my code as what you said (correct code)

Answer (score 1):

get Click event by using Following code.....

```
     View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

     view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            System.out.println("Clicked!!!"); /// Write your Code for Progress Here....
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what you mean "View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);" i am not getting   here what layout i have  to use

Comment: Parent Layout (Root Container)